# how to wrap the div containing modal fade class in the outer div (for $modal angular-ui)

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog, angular-ui

I tried looking for the solution but couldnt find anything related to this. I am really new to angular. 
I want the modal fade class generated in the $modal angular-ui bootstrap modal to be wrapped inside a div which has a global-class which covers the entire modal code. But I dont know how to achieve that.

I was able to add custom css class to the **modal fade**{{customClass}} but what is want is to have an outer div with this global-class above this modal fade class.

Any help is appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

The only real option would be to edit `ui-bootstrap-tpls.js`:

From line 3529 in ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.10.0.js:

```
angular.module("template/modal/window.html", []).run(["$templateCache", function($templateCache) {
  $templateCache.put("template/modal/window.html",
    "<div tabindex=\"-1\" class=\"modal fade {{ windowClass }}\" ng-class=\"{in: animate}\" ng-style=\"{'z-index': 1050 + index*10, display: 'block'}\" ng-click=\"close($event)\">\n" +
    "    <div class=\"modal-dialog\"><div class=\"modal-content\" ng-transclude></div></div>\n" +
    "</div>");
}]);
```

Comment: I wish I could do that but thats not the case..Is there any other way to do this anywhere but not in the minified version or library??